# Audit mule inbound outbound messages

Tags: mule

we are trying to audit all incoming/outgoing messages, header information in our mule flow.

For same we have tried to use 'wire-tap' which we dint found so useful also its working on mule 3.6.1 but giving error in 3.7.

[image: sample flow with wire tap]

Any idea/suggestion for auditing?

Ok let me add some more details:

What we are trying to do is- Whatever message comes or flows via flow components we want to copy it in some sub flow (say in queue) without interrupting the main flow so that we can check the message.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it work in several ways

1) Wire tap is one of the choice. You can route your messages asynchronously to sub flow and sub flow will do the auditing work. But I don't know why you didn't found wiretap useful. Can you explain in more.

2) All the messages your receive from the main flow, those you can post to JMS queue. So another flow will read from there and do the auditing work. Use of this multiple projects can use the same piece of code and post JMS queue for auditing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many different ways and you kind of mentioned them in your question such as logger component and interceptor.

All the headers are available as message properties so if you log the entire message they are shown. Simply put an logger component after the inbound endpoint and one before the outbound endpoint and this is easily done.

If you need some log entries transformation you could always put that in a wire tap so you don't interfere with the functionality of your flow.